# Split file content and store into array or iterate throgh file content by delimeter

Tags: linux, bash, awk, ifs

I have below file say MemberFile.txt. which contains records separated by delimiter '#' which starts on newline and is a single character of that line. As such there are three records.

```
3RECORDSFILE
#
[FIRSTNAME      ]   FirstName01
[MIDDLENAME     ]   MiddleName01
[LASTNAME       ]   LastName01
[ADDRESS       Q]   AddressOf #001 Pune
[ADDRESS       S]   AddressOf #001
#
[FIRSTNAME      ]   NameFirst02
[MIDDLENAME     ]   MiddleName02
[LASTNAME       ]   LastName02
[ADDRESS       Q]   AddressOf [002
[ADDRESS       N]   Addres Mumbai sOf [002
#
[FIRSTNAME      ]   03FirstName
[MIDDLENAME     ]   MiddleName03
[LASTNAME       ]   LastName03
[ADDRESS       Q]   Address Of 003]
```

How we can iterate through records using IFS without `cat` the whole file. I tried something below with no avail. Looks like its reading it line by line and not by specified IFS. Not sure where it is wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='^#$' read r
do
echo $r
#do something more
done < MemberFile.txt
```

Other option I tried using awk. Specify delimeter and store into an array. That is also not yielding desired result.

```
arr=($(awk -F='^#$' '{print $1}' Member.txt))
for i in $arr
do
echo $I
#do something more
done
```

Can you please have a look and correct me where its going wrong. I am well fresh to this bash scripting. I need to perform some operations again on each record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `gnu awk` to break down input into records separated by `#\n`:

```
awk -v RS='#\n' 'NR>1{print "==================", NR, "================"; print}' file
================== 2 ================
[FIRSTNAME      ]   FirstName01
[MIDDLENAME     ]   MiddleName01
[LASTNAME       ]   LastName01
[ADDRESS       Q]   AddressOf #001 Pune
[ADDRESS       S]   AddressOf #001

================== 3 ================
[FIRSTNAME      ]   NameFirst02
[MIDDLENAME     ]   MiddleName02
[LASTNAME       ]   LastName02
[ADDRESS       Q]   AddressOf [002
[ADDRESS       N]   Addres Mumbai sOf [002

================== 4 ================
[FIRSTNAME      ]   03FirstName
[MIDDLENAME     ]   MiddleName03
[LASTNAME       ]   LastName03
[ADDRESS       Q]   Address Of 003]
```

You can do operations on each record, such as printing all `FIRSTNAME` using this awk command:

```
awk -v RS='#\n' 'NR>1{print $3}' file

FirstName01
NameFirst02
03FirstName
```

Comment: its working Anubhava. How I can get the whole record stored into variable.

Comment: It was '\r\n' required instead of '\n'. Sorry as blindly run without lil change

Comment: Why do you want to store each record? Whatever processing you want to do, do it inside the awk. Don't involve `bash` in this.

Comment: May be I am failing to get that using awk. can you please help as how same can be achieved here in the curly brackets.     `awk -v RS='#\n' 'NR>1{  #Get FIRSTNAME value and store into variable,   # Check if record contains Mumbai or Pune and echo "YES"}' file`

Comment: Spend some time in reading a good awk tutorial. What you're asking can be done using: `awk -v RS='#\n' 'NR>1 && /Mumbai|Pune/{print "YES"}' file`. I have already provided an example to get all `FIRSTNAME` fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely need to use an array, you could do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
arry=""
cnt=0
while read -r line
do
        if [[ "$line" == "#" ]]
        then
                cnt=$(($cnt+1))
        else
                arry[$cnt]=${arry[$cnt]}$line"\n"
        fi
done < Member.txt
for ((i=1;i<=$cnt;i++))
do
        echo -e ${arry[$i]}
        # do some other stuff here
done
```

We first take each line of Member.txt in a loop and increment a counter when "#" is encountered and using this counter to create with each element holding each block of data. We then loop through the array and print out each block, doing what ever else is required.

Comment: Hi Raman, while this works great ... for me performance is a matter.

Answer (score 0):

anubhava's answer seems useful, but not actually there if you need to get the input into bash variables. The full process for this is to read the records into a scripting language (as anubhava did), then to print the records out with a null delimiter, then read the records into bash variables. Use a null delimiter since you know the text won't contain nulls. A key is to let the `read` command use the null character as its delimiter.

I used perl instead of awk for the first part:

```
cat Member.txt | perl -e 'use warnings; use strict; my $stdin_raw; { local $/; $stdin_raw = <STDIN>; }; my @records = split(/\n#/m, $stdin_raw);
```

print(join("\0", @records), "\0");' | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' record; do echo "Got record: $record"; done

However, since all you're doing is replacing "#" with null, you can use sed for this simple substitution:

```
cat Member.txt | sed 's/^#$/\x00/' | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' record; do echo "Got record: $record"; done
```

Note that `IFS=` is needed to prevent `read` from only consuming one word at a time. `-d $'\0'` sets the delimiter to the null character. `-r` is for raw mode: it tells `read` to ignore special characters in the data.

But I agree with anubhava about one thing: scripting languages are more powerful and useful than bash for text processing. I suggest perl instead of awk, since awk's rules aren't like an ordinary programming language. Despite writing around a hundred scripts in awk, I never got the hang of it. I found that debugging awk scripts is hard, even with the documentation in front of me. Awk is a simple language that gets ugly when you try to do complex things. Perl has a steeper initial learning curve, but it stops feeling like black magic much sooner.